# Can't ping 253.100.156.93 from Linux

Tags: routing, ip, ifconfig

At a remote location, there is a chinese ethernet enabled POS printer.

It somehow garbled it's configuration, and its self-test now says that its IP address is 253.100.156.93, (which is inside a IANA reserved block)

No biggie, I thought - I will just `ifconfig eth0 add 253.100.156.92` and log into the printer's config panel and reset the IP.

Strangely, after adding that IP address, `ifconfig` still doesn't show it.

`ip a` does, though:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:27:0e:1d:07:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.209.99/16 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 253.100.156.92/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

but i still can't ping or visit 253.100.156.93.

Is there something I am missing? Why does `ifconfig` not show that address, but `ip a` does? Is there some built-in filtering of reserved IANA addresses in the kernel?

Comment: ifconfig on Linux is obsolete. Don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `ifconfig`, as you see it can't display multiple IP addresses.

Your problem is visible in the output of `ip a`: `253.100.156.92/32`

Delete that address and add it with mask /24.

```
ip a del 253.100.156.92/32 dev eth0
ip a add 253.100.156.92/24 dev eth0
```

Comment: But for the record: `ifconfig` usually does show multiple ip addresses, no problem.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Fixed.

Comment: @MoritzvonSchweinitz On my older computer `ifconfig` doesn't, and on the newer, it is no longer present. There may have been other versions in between, but `ifconfig` is deprecated and `ip` should be used.